# Oracle find all users I created (excluding Oracle accounts)

Tags: oracle

Is there a way to find all user accounts in Oracle which have been created by me?
The `SELECT * FROM ALL_USERS;` returns all users in Oracle, but there seems to be no way of defining the 'owner' of the account (ORC_SYS would be nice) so I can add a clause like 
`'WHERE OWNER !+ 'ORC_SYS'` or something.

Thanks in advance

KS

Comment: The "creator" of a user is not stored, but you can filter out those that are managed by Oracle itself: `where oracle_maintained = 'N'`

Comment: The information you require may be stored in audit logs. But this is hard to mine.

Answer (score 1):

If its only the users created by oracle at install time you want to exclude you can properly do it filtering on user_id. Normally these users will have the lowest numbers:

Ajust the 35 to your installation.

```
Select * from dba_users where user_id > 35;
```

And if you are running 12c or above there is a column "Oracle_maintained" telling you if it is an oracle created user.

```
Select * from dba_users where oracle_maintained = 'N';
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to `dba_users` and your Oracle's version is 12.1 and above, you can filter by `oracle_maintained` column.

Otherwise, there is no "official" way to distinguish between oracle internal users and your own.

There are some indirect ways, though:

1. Filter by `all_users.created` column. Mostly, internal users are created when the database is created, so your users will be after this date. You may find the database creation time in `v$database.created` .
2. Filter by `all_users.user_id`. As above, mostly, internal users are created when the database is created, so they get low user_id. There are some exceptions for several users like SYSBACKUP, SYSDG.

Both ways may produce incorrect results when internal users are created much later than the database creation - for example when an Oracle Option is reinstalled.

Answer (score -1):

Should you try:

```
SELECT * FROM dba_users;
```

Comment: This will show **every** user, including the users created by installing Oracle features.